# BlazeDs Object Mapping from Flex to Java

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5, blazeds

We can map flex to java objects using remoteclass

I have flex object with attributes a, b , c all have datatype as string

So i also need to have Java object with following atributes a , b , c with string datatype

Is it compulsory to have exact number of attributes with similar datatype?
If not then what error does it throw?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use all attributes of JAVA object in your flex object otherwise you will encounter "ArgumentError: Error #1063: Argument count mismatch on entities"

Also flex object can have additional attributes which are not defined in JAVA object